# Show number of search results at the TOP

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface

Every search engine out there displays the number of results at the top of the result listing. Yet SO and after several requests and no feedback, still does not display the number. It feels like hiding the number is intentional!

Only showing number of pages and result/per page at the bottom is not very helpful. Plus if the results are more than 500, you have no idea what the number is.

Comment: Yep, they only show for a tag only search.

Comment: tag only search is useless for me.

Comment: I am aware of that post. I even have a comment there. Mine is to reiterate and emphasize the position.

Comment: I can't say that i have *ever* cared for more than detail than the page count. What's the use case?

Comment: Because when I see I got too many search results back, I know I need to narrow down the results by using more/better search keywords. The fewer results back the better the result quality because they are more targeted. Right now I have to go to the bottom of the page to have an idea how many results I got.